# How to convert a list of EntityA to a List of EntityB if conversion of a list inside is need?

Tags: java, spring

For example,
I have

```
public class Restaurant {
String address;
    private List<Dish> dishes;
}
```

And I need to convert a List of Restaurants to a list of RestaurantDto's. Inside for each object a convertion of a List of type Dish to a type DishDto is needed.

```
public class RestaurantDto {
    private String name;
    private List<DishDto> dishes;
}
```

Comment: What is inside Dish and DishDto? addAll() method might come in handy if it's all the same. Otherwise, you can write a convertList() method and modify List<Dish> to List<DishDto> inside that method. Return List<DishDto> from the convertList() method. But, again, need to know what is inside Dish and DishDto to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: You can use any of the mapping libraries here like `Mapstruct` to map entities to DTO.